# ellipsize disable initial text

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have a strange behavior with the use of `singleLine=true` and `ellipsize=start` with a Button.

First of all, the declaration of my button :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/enterDeparture"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/field_button"
    android:text="@string/research_enterDeparture"
    android:textColor="@drawable/field_button_textcolor"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

With this declaration, no text is displayed inside the button. But if I write `Log.d(TAG, "the text is : " + findViewById(R.id.enterDeparture));`, the LogCat gives me the correct value...

I tried to set the text programatically, either in the `onCreateView()` and in the `onResume()` methods : same behavior. But if I set the text really later of if I put an AlertDialog over my screen, the content come back immediatly...

To finish, if I remove the two lines `android:ellipsize="start"` and `android:singleLine="true"`, everything is normal : my text is displayed in the first time.

**EDIT**

I tried to remove the `singleLine=true` line : the initial content is actually displayed but the ellipsize behavior doesn't work anymore...

So I tried with `maxLines=1` : the initial content is displayed, but the "..." are not shown anymore (the content is just truncated).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the height value:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You could be elipsising your text to ... and because the button padding it could be being hidden.

Also you want to try this instead:

```
Log.d(TAG, "the text is : " + ((Button)findViewById(R.id.enterDeparture)).getText())
```

Comment: this doesn't change anything. However, I need the fixed height.